# Insert only those objects that are not already in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

I have a scenario where an item is being tagged with several tags, some of these are already in the database, others not.

I am imagining that I need to Attach() the tags that exist already and AddObject() the ones that aren't. This must be a common scenario, what's the 'best-practices' approach to this?

Comment: When you say 'the tag already exists in the database', do you mean that (a) that specific instance exists or, (b) a tag exists with the same value?

Comment: well its coming as a string from http, I want to match existing tags with the same value as that string, and not create duplicates. so b) I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only real way to deal with this is

- Find which items already exist
- Split your collection into two groups:

  - new items
  - existing items
- Add the new items, and attach the existing items, if required.

So split your tags like this

```
var tags = context.Tags.Where(t => t.ItemId = itemId) // search via your item
   .Select(t => t.TagValue);

var newTags = myItem.Tags.Where(t => !tags.Contains(t.TagValue));
var existingTags = myItem.Tags.Where(t => tags.Contains(t.TagValue));
```

then add & attach as appropriate.